# How do I access Original and Modified versions of strongly typed DataRow?

Tags: c#, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, unit-of-work

I'm writing code to emulate a unit of work pattern in my winforms over datasets application.

I have the following:

```
foreach (EomApp1.Formss.Accounting.Data.AccountingView.AccountingViewRow 
                in accountingView.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                 // break point -> immediate window
```

immediate window:

```
modified.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Cost/Unit", DataRowVersion.Original]
1
modified.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Cost/Unit", DataRowVersion.Current]
0
```

Is there any way to access the above information using strongly typed datasets? (in my example, accountingView **is**, but I don't know how to get at the changed DataRowVersion objects without using the string names of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I know there is none.
To get rid of the magic strings you could do

```
modified.Tables[0].Rows[0][Tables[0].CostUnitColumn.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Current]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the [DataRowExtensions.Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347601.aspx) extension method in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly solve this for you? Note parameters for `DataColumn` and `DataRowVersion`.